# Why the need for a mask when performing Fast Fourier Transform?

Tags: r, fft

I'm trying to find out the peak frequencies hidden in my data using the fft() method in R. While preparing the data, a more experienced user recommends to create a "mask" (more after explaining the details), that does give me the exact diagram I'm looking for. The problem is, I don't understand what it does or why it's needed.

To give some context, I'm working with .txt files with around 12000 entries each. It's voltage vs. time information, and the expected result is just a sinusoidal wave with a clear peak frequency that should be close to 1-2 Hz. This is an example of what one of those files look like:

[image: My plotted data]

I've been trying to use the Fast Fourier Transform method fft() implemented in R to find the peak frequencies and get a diagram that reflected them clearly. At first, I calculate some things that I understand are going to be useful, like the Nyquist frequency and the range of frequencies I'll show in the final graph:

```
    n = length(variable)
dt = time[5]-time[4] 
df = 1/(max(time))  #Find out the "unit" frequency
fnyquist = 1/(2*dt) #The Nyquist frequency
    f = seq(-fnyquist, fnyquist-df, by=df) #These are the frequencies I'll plot
```

But when I plot the absolute value of what fft(data) calculates vs. the range of frequencies, I get this:

[image: abs(fft(data)) vs. frequency]

The peak frequency seems to be close to 50 Hz, but I know that's not the case. It should be close to 1 Hz. I'm a complete newbie in R and in Fourier analysis, so after researching a little, I found [in a Swiss page](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-February/425493.html) that this can be solved by creating a "mask", which is actually just a vector with a repeatting patern (1, -1, 1, -1...) with the same length as my data vector itself:

```
    mask=rep(c(1, -1),length.out=n)
```

Then if I multiply my data vector by this mask and plot the results:

```
    results = mask*data
    plot(f,abs(fft(results)),type="h")
```

I get what I was looking for. (This is the graph after limiting the x-axis to a reasonable scale).
[image: Right frequency diagram!]

So, what's the mask actually doing? I undestand it's changing my data point signs in an alternate manner, but I don't get why it would take the infered peak frequencies from ~50 Hz to the correct result of ~1 Hz.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your "mask" is one of two methods of performing an fftshift, which is commonly done to center the 0 Hz output of an FFT in the middle of a graph or plot (instead of at the left edge, with the negative frequencies wrapping around to the right edge).

To perform an fftshift, you can hetrodyne or modulate your data (by Fs/2) before the FFT, or simply do a circular shift by 50% after the FFT.  Both produce the same result.  They are the same due to the shift property of the DFT.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've checked what the fftshift function does (in MATLAB, at least) and it switches the right and left halves of a vector. So I guess multiplying the initial data alternately by +1 and -1 gives the same results because of this, right? (Thanks for your answer! I decided to use the fftshift function because it'll easier to explain than justifying my decision to use the "mask").